# XWiki - Database (How XWO_ID is created ?)

Tags: database, xwiki

I know how XWD_ID (xwikidoc) is created, but I don't know how XWO_ID (xwikiobject) is 
created. I know that this is the same ID for tables xwikidates, xwikiintegers, xwikilargestrings,... But I don't know how it is created. 
Can you help me ?

Thanks,

Caroline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All IDs are assigned manually so far, and they are obtained from the entity's getId() method. For objects, this is [BaseElement.getId()](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-oldcore/src/main/java/com/xpn/xwiki/objects/BaseElement.java#L186) which is the new method of computing IDs (introduced in 4.0). Up to 3.5, it used to be [BaseCollection.getId()](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/xwiki-platform-3.5/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-oldcore/src/main/java/com/xpn/xwiki/objects/BaseCollection.java#L132) which is actually the [hashCode](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/xwiki-platform-3.5/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-oldcore/src/main/java/com/xpn/xwiki/objects/BaseObject.java#L146) of the object, which is the hashcode of the string obtained by concatenating the document name, the XClass name, and the object number.